# FFmpeg leaks memory after closing activity

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I'm trying to implements a rtsp player based on the [roman10 tutorial](https://github.com/roman10/android-ffmpeg-tutorial/blob/master/android-ffmpeg-tutorial02/jni/tutorial02.c).
I can play a stream but each time i leave the activity a lot of memory is leaked.
After some research it appears that the bitmap which is a global jobject is the cause :

```
jobject createBitmap(JNIEnv *pEnv, int pWidth, int pHeight) {
    int i;
    //get Bitmap class and createBitmap method ID
    jclass javaBitmapClass = (jclass)(*pEnv)->FindClass(pEnv, "android/graphics/Bitmap");
    jmethodID mid = (*pEnv)->GetStaticMethodID(pEnv, javaBitmapClass, "createBitmap", "(IILandroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;");
    //create Bitmap.Config
    //reference: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1548728
    const wchar_t* configName = L"ARGB_8888";
    int len = wcslen(configName);
    jstring jConfigName;
    if (sizeof(wchar_t) != sizeof(jchar)) {
        //wchar_t is defined as different length than jchar(2 bytes)
        jchar* str = (jchar*)malloc((len+1)*sizeof(jchar));
        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            str[i] = (jchar)configName[i];
        }
        str[len] = 0;
        jConfigName = (*pEnv)->NewString(pEnv, (const jchar*)str, len);
    } else {
        //wchar_t is defined same length as jchar(2 bytes)
        jConfigName = (*pEnv)->NewString(pEnv, (const jchar*)configName, len);
    }
    jclass bitmapConfigClass = (*pEnv)->FindClass(pEnv, "android/graphics/Bitmap$Config");
    jobject javaBitmapConfig = (*pEnv)->CallStaticObjectMethod(pEnv, bitmapConfigClass,
            (*pEnv)->GetStaticMethodID(pEnv, bitmapConfigClass, "valueOf", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;"), jConfigName);
    //create the bitmap
    return (*pEnv)->CallStaticObjectMethod(pEnv, javaBitmapClass, mid, pWidth, pHeight, javaBitmapConfig);
}
```

The bitmap is created like this :

```
bitmap = createBitmap(...);
```

When the activity is closed this method is called :

```
void finish(JNIEnv *pEnv) {
    //unlock the bitmap
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(pEnv, bitmap);
    av_free(buffer);
    // Free the RGB image
    av_free(frameRGBA);
    // Free the YUV frame
    av_free(decodedFrame);
    // Close the codec
    avcodec_close(codecCtx);
    // Close the video file
    avformat_close_input(&formatCtx);
}
```

The bitmap seems to never be freed, just unlocked.

What should i do be sure to get back all the memory ?

Note : i'm using ffmpeg 2.5.2.

Comment: You don't "free" `jobject`s; you delete the references to them. Have you acquired a global reference to `bitmap` somewhere (with `NewGlobalRef`)? If so, not deleting that reference would prevent the object from being garbage-collected.

Comment: The bitmap is created with a call to GetStaticObjectMethod() , see : https://github.com/roman10/android-ffmpeg-tutorial/blob/master/android-ffmpeg-tutorial02/jni/tutorial02.c#L95